# Nama mantras for Devi Parvati in shaanta swarup without bija aksharashas?

Tags: mantras, devi, devi-bhagavata-purana, upasana, bijakshara

Can someone list down some nana mantras of Devi Parvati which do not contain Bija aksharas,and that which meditate on Mother’s calm forms?

Thank you.